# Validación de entry box en python tkinter

Tags: tkinter, python-3.7, class, self

tengo este código en el cual intento que la entry box acepte solo numeros, el código corre bien, pero cuando comienzo a escribir, la terminal me arroja:
**TypeError: marco.**init**..validar_entrada() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'**
Por favor si me pudieran decir donde está el error, gracias. Aquí dejo el código:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.ttk import *
import customtkinter
from customtkinter import *

root =customtkinter.CTk()
root.geometry("500x500")

class marco():
   
   
   def __init__(self, master) :
       self.marco_prov=customtkinter.CTkFrame(master, border_color=("black"), border_width=2)
       self.marco_prov.grid(column=0, row=4, pady=5, padx=5, columnspan=2)
       
       self.labelprov=customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.marco_prov, text="Proveedor :")
       self.labelprov.grid(column=0, row=0, pady=5, padx=5)
       self.entryprov=customtkinter.CTkComboBox(self.marco_prov)
       self.entryprov.grid(column=1, row=0)
       self.boton_agregar=customtkinter.CTkButton(self.marco_prov,  text="Agregar")
       self.boton_agregar.grid(column=2, row=0, pady=5, padx=5)
       
       def validar_entrada(self, text):
           return text.isdecimal()
       
       self.label_n=customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.marco_prov, text="N° de Guía")
       self.label_n.grid(column=0, row=1, pady=5, padx=5)
       self.entry_num_guia=customtkinter.CTkEntry(self.marco_prov, validate="key", validatecommand=(self.marco_prov.register(validar_entrada), "%S"))
       self.entry_num_guia.grid(column=1, row=1, pady=5, padx=5)
       self.entry_num_guia.configure(textvariable=tkinter.IntVar)
      
marco(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tu función validar_entrada acepta dos argumentos, pero está recibiendo uno solo. Como la función validar_entrada no es un método de clase, no tiene sentido pensar que recibirás a self.

Comment: Gracias, pero ¿como lo arreglo? Disculpa si es obvia la respuesta, soy novato.

Comment: No pasa nada c: simplemente tenes que quitar self de los parametros de validar_entrada.

Comment: Gracias hermano, funcionó perfecto.

Comment: De nada Carlos nwn